# Default font selection behaves strangely

Tags: fonts, emacs27

After upgrading to Emacs 27.1, my default font changed to adobe courier. I would like to use Anonymous Pro or Inconsolata, but attempts to change it using `M-x customize-face RET default` fail. I am at a loss to describe the behavior as it seems to me irregular and I am not sure where to begin. Setting it to Anonymous Pro or Inconsolata, which so far as I can tell are in fact installed on my system and go by those names, causes the font to fall back to a serif font that looks like times. I am using the KDE Font Management utility to see what fonts are installed. Running `xfontsel` to look at which fonts are installed gives a different list, but entering information from it produces indeterminate effects---the font does change, but I can't tell if it's falling back to courier or a default serif font. So far as I can tell, it usually does make the right change, which I can test for instance if I use `etl` for the foundry and `fixed` for the family. The emacs font matches what that font looks like in the xfontsel menu.

So---as should be clear---not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

I'm using Emacs 27.1, on OpenSuse Leap 15.2, KDE.

Comment: Emacs 27 switched the font backend to Harfbuzz, so it's possible this is a bug. You might be able to set a frame parameter like `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font-backend . xft))` to go back to non-Harfbuzz font rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution"---the problem has been fixed, although I don't know why. Maybe this will help someone else experiencing this kind of instability.

Tinkering, I used `S-down mouse-1` as instructed at [the EmacsWiki Set Fonts page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#toc1). Emacs crashed when I selected Anonymous Pro. I deleted the desktop on general principle. After I restarted emacs, I could select Anonymous Pro using `S-down mouse-1` to change the face in a buffer. Then I could set it persisently as the default face using customize.

Comment: I've also had had 27 break fonts (e.g. all emoji visible through `C-x 8 RET` Can you clarify what you mean by "deleted the desktop"?

Comment: "Deleted the desktop" is probably too strong. I turned desktop-save-mode off (`M-x desktop-save-mode`); it's on by default in my setup.